# QThread in PySide2 started but slot not fired on started signal

Tags: python, multithreading, pyside2, qthread

**EDIT**: I made variables more descriptive, added buttons to trigger threads, changed issue description

Expected behaviour after starting given thread by clicking button :

- ***thread X is triggered and started***
- -> ***worker.make_some_action_X***
- -> ***worker.some_action_X_thread_finished*** Signal is emitted
- -> ***controller.on_finished_X*** is called.

What I actually get is:

*working Thread 1 as expected but for thread 2 and 3*:

- ***thread 2 (thread 3)*** is triggered and started but no more is executed,
- they are frozen/hung untill I run Thread 1 again, then process for Thread 2 and 3 is continued

The base problem that this example is based on can be solved with one QThread instead of three but the main purpose and subject of asking for help is to understand what I need to do to make this particular example with three threads working and why it is not working under Windows 10 as expected (under Linux I got expected results as well as in debug mode in PyCharm under Windows 10).

Just guessing: is it thread priority issue? The problem is related to the event loop or ownership of worker by given thread? Do you have in mind any useful articles related to my issue?

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    some_action_1_thread_finished = QtCore.Signal()
    some_action_2_thread_finished = QtCore.Signal()
    some_action_3_thread_finished = QtCore.Signal()

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.flag = None

    QtCore.Slot()
    def make_some_action_1(self):
        self.flag = 0
        print(f'I am in make_some_action_1')
        print(f'action 1 : {self}')
        self.some_action_1_thread_finished.emit()

    QtCore.Slot()
    def make_some_action_2(self):
        # time.sleep(10)
        self.flag = 20.1
        print(f'I am in make_some_action_2')
        print(f'action 2 : {self}')
        self.some_action_2_thread_finished.emit()

    QtCore.Slot()
    def make_some_action_3(self):
        # time.sleep(5)
        self.flag = 101.3
        print(f'I am in make_some_action_3')
        print(f'action 3 : {self}')
        self.some_action_3_thread_finished.emit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.flag}'


class Controller(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.worker = Worker()

        self.some_action_1_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.some_action_1_thread) # should be moved to the specific method ran during thread triggering
        print(':: checkpoint 1')
        self.some_action_2_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        # self.worker.moveToThread(self.some_action_2_thread)
        print(':: checkpoint 2')
        self.some_action_3_thread = QtCore.QThread()
        # self.worker.moveToThread(self.some_action_3_thread)
        print(':: checkpoint 3')

        self.main_window = MainWindow()
        self.main_window.show()

        self.worker.some_action_1_thread_finished.connect(self.some_action_1_thread.quit)
        self.worker.some_action_1_thread_finished.connect(self.on_finished_1)
        self.some_action_1_thread.started.connect(self.worker.make_some_action_1)
        print(':: checkpoint A')
        self.worker.some_action_2_thread_finished.connect(self.some_action_2_thread.quit)
        self.worker.some_action_2_thread_finished.connect(self.on_finished_2)
        self.some_action_2_thread.started.connect(self.worker.make_some_action_2)
        print(':: checkpoint B')
        self.worker.some_action_3_thread_finished.connect(self.some_action_3_thread.quit)
        self.worker.some_action_3_thread_finished.connect(self.on_finished_3)
        self.some_action_3_thread.started.connect(self.worker.make_some_action_3)
        print(':: checkpoint C')
        self.main_window.exit_button.clicked.connect(self.main_window.close)
        self.main_window.thread_1_button.clicked.connect(self.on_thread_1_button)
        self.main_window.thread_2_button.clicked.connect(self.on_thread_2_button)
        self.main_window.thread_3_button.clicked.connect(self.on_thread_3_button)

    def trigger_thread_1(self):
        self.some_action_1_thread.start()
        print('thread 1 started')
        # self.some_action_2_thread.start()
        # self.some_action_3_thread.start()
        # time.sleep(10)

    def trigger_thread_2(self):
        self.some_action_2_thread.start()
        print('thread 2 started')

    def trigger_thread_3(self):
        self.some_action_3_thread.start()
        print('thread 3 started')

    def on_finished_1(self):
        print('FINISHED, stopping thread 1')

    def on_finished_2(self):
        print('FINISHED, stopping thread 2')
        # self.trigger_thread_3()

    def on_finished_3(self):
        print('FINISHED, stopping thread 3')

    def on_thread_1_button(self):
        self.trigger_thread_1()

    def on_thread_2_button(self):
        self.trigger_thread_2()

    def on_thread_3_button(self):
        self.trigger_thread_3()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.exit_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Exit')
        self.thread_1_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Thread 1')
        self.thread_2_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Thread 2')
        self.thread_3_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Thread 3')

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.exit_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.thread_1_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.thread_2_button)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.thread_3_button)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication([])

    controller = Controller()

    print(f'MAIN Process: worker flag : {controller.worker}')
    app.exec_()
    print(f'After event loop: worker flag : {controller.worker}')
    print('END')
```

***EDIT 2*** :

It seems that solution to make it working is:

- move the `worker` to given thread X at the moment the thread X is triggered

```py
def trigger_thread_X(self):
    self.worker.moveToThread(self.some_action_X_thread)
    # ...
```

- move the `worker` back to the main thread after some_action is made:

```py
def make_some_action_X(self):
    # ...
    self.moveToThread(app.thread())
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your objective, and your example is a bit convoluted, so I'm under the impression that you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you clarify what is the final purpose that you're trying to show with your code?

Comment: So my main concern in this example is why `a.make_some_action_2` is not running after clicking `Thread 2` button.

Comment: It helps me to better understand how QThread works and help me with refactoring unworking code I have met at project

Comment: that answer isn't very useful. We already know what you want to know, what we need to understand is what you're **actually** trying to do with your *real* code. What's the purpose of the "unworking code"? How/why should those 3 "threads" work like it seems you're trying to do? Was that "code" working before your refactoring attempt? Did it already use threading as you're trying to? In any case, I tested your code and it "works", even if your usage of threads is a bit unorthodox, and that's exactly why we need to understand what's your final goal, as your example is too abstract and confused.